# How to set dialog to show from the bottom of the screen?

Tags: android

So I am trying to create a dialog to [mimic this](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-sheets.html#bottom-sheets-modal-bottom-sheets) but when I set the gravity to bottom it still shows full screen. I would like the dialog to start at the first item and go up from there, what is the best way to do this? All help is much appreciated.

[image: picture]

Here is the activity I show the dialog in:

```
public class BottomSheetActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RVAdapter.ClickListener {

    public Intent messageIntent;
    public String result = "";
    public String fullList = "";
    public RVAdapter adapter;
    public LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    public RecyclerView RV;
    public Dialog sheet;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        messageIntent = getIntent();
        fullList = messageIntent.getStringExtra("fullList");
        adapter = new RVAdapter(this, getData(fullList));
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        sheet = new Dialog(this);
        sheet.setContentView(R.layout.recycler_layout);
        RV = (RecyclerView) sheet.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        RV.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        RV.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.setClickListener(this);
        sheet.setTitle("Boom");
        Window window = sheet.getWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = window.getAttributes();
        params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
        window.setAttributes(params);
        sheet.show();
    }

    public List<MainInfo> getData(String fullList) {
        List<MainInfo> data = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] smallData = fullList.split(",");
        for (int i = 0; i < smallData.length; i++) {
            MainInfo current = new MainInfo();
            current.listText = smallData[i];
            //current.iconId = 777;
            data.add(current);
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if ( TaskerPlugin.Setting.hostSupportsVariableReturn(messageIntent.getExtras())) {
            Bundle vars = new Bundle();
            vars.putString("%bs_command", result);
            TaskerPlugin.Setting.signalFinish(getApplicationContext(), messageIntent, TaskerPlugin.Setting.RESULT_CODE_OK, vars);
        }
        //finalCommand = "snackbarcommand=:=" + result;
        //AutoAppsThirdParty.sendCommand(this, finalCommand);
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void itemClicked(View view, int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Toast.makeText(BottomSheetActivity.this, "Banana", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 1:
                Toast.makeText(BottomSheetActivity.this, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the screens you linked use a dialog at all. It's just a view at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: @Coeffect Huh, I guess it could be, but do you if what I am after is possible with a dialog?

Comment: I doubt it. Dialogs are generally created in the middle of the screen and don't touch the edges of the screen. It shouldn't be too hard to create a simple view that pops up at the bottom of the screen. Just throw a RelativeLayout as the last element in your Activity's layout xml file that covers the entire screen, then inflate views into it. Animations might be a bit trickier but doable.

Comment: @Coeffect So this library here: https://github.com/soarcn/BottomSheet/ uses dialogs to do exactly what I am looking for. Now the reason I am not just using the library is because I need the layout to be configurable programatically.

Comment: That's a neat library. Looks like they're changing the LayoutParams of the Window, which is interesting. I think the important bit is the onCreate(), you might be able to just selectively copy some of this: https://github.com/soarcn/BottomSheet/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/cocosw/bottomsheet/BottomSheet.java#L434

Comment: @Coeffect So I think I figured it out. It is because I am using a recyclerview inside the dialog that it extends the full height of the screen. Do you know if there is either a way for it to not be of full height, or a different method to show a dynamic amount of items inside of the sheet (maybe a list adapter)? Or is there a way to use the library and just create a menu problematically? Thanks for you help